# Как выводить графическое поле в отчете Rave Reports?

Tags: ravereport, delphi, graphics

Таблица содержит графическое поле `Graphic`. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы это поле печаталось в отчете. Как сделать? (Delphi 7)

Comment: Нужна технология именно Rave Reports, или же Quick Report тоже подойдёт?

Comment: В принципе тоже подойдет, мне главное отчет сделать =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если главное сделать, тогда требуется сначала установить компоненты Quick Report (они идут вместе с Delphi 7, но по умолчанию не ставятся). Установка: идём в меню Component -> Install Packages... в открывшемся окне жмём кнопку Add, затем переходим в каталог, где установлена Delphi (по умолчанию - шаг вверх), заходим в папку Bin и выбираем файл dclqrt70.bpl, затем жмём Ok. По умолчанию закладка с этими компонентами установится в самый конец. Если есть опыт составления отчётов в MS Access и Delphi, то ничего сложного, думаю, не будет. Сам я не смогу описать работу с Quick Report - дело хлопотное. Прочитать про работу с Quick Report можно в книге М. Е. Фленова "Библия Delphi" или на сайте http://www.intuit.ru/
в курсе "Программирование баз данных в Delphi" - [вот ссылка](http://www.intuit.ru/department/se/dbpdelphi/) на этот курс (лекция 11 - то, что Вам нужно). Могу прислать пример отчёта с картинками на E-mail.

Comment: Благодарю за отклик! Последую Вашему совету, потом напишу, что да как.

Comment: Все сделала, все работает, еще раз спасибо, выручили! =)